# Select Top 100 Groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have thousands of groups in a table, something like :

```
1.. 
1..
2..
2..
2..
2..
3..
3..
.
.
.
10000..
10000..
```

How can i make a select that give me the Top 3 groups each time.

I Want something like select Top 3 from rows , but it have to return the first three groups not the first three rows.

Comment: you have same record or different record??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you perhaps expand a bit on what you are trying to do?

Comment: do you want only the group id, or some aggregated data too? in which order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
;with cte as (

select distinct groupId from mytable order by groupid 
)
select * from mytable where TheGroupId in (select top 3 groupdid from cte)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DENSE_RANK` to assign a number to each group. All members of the same group will have the same number. Then in an outer query, select top 3 groups:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rnk
      FROM mytable ) t
WHERE t.rnk <= 3
```

The above query assumes that `id` is the column used to group records together.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb577/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use Ranking function `Row_Number()` :

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY GroupId
                   ORDER BY GroupId) AS [rn]
        FROM   YourTable) t
WHERE  rn <= 3
```

Check this [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) for details of all ranking functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sql TOP statement that does this

```
SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s) FROM table_name;
```

a description of what it does and how it is used in alternative sql statements for example for mysql and ms access can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

My bad i misread your question, this will return the top rows not groups, could you explain what you are trying to do in more detail?

Comment: Hey just so you know, you ask questions in the comments not in the answers. You should edit or delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY [Group] ASC)rn
     FROM TableName
    )A
WHERE rn <= 3
```